# Converting arrays of different ordinal types in a bunch instead of one element after another

Tags: arrays, delphi

Just for curiosity: I am looking for a solution of a theoretical problem to optimze the use of data structures in applications.

Let's assume there are the following types (currently using DXE7 if that matters):

```
type
  TMyType1 = 0..4294967295; 
  TMyType2 = 0..65535;
  TMyArrayType1 = array of TMyType1;
  TMyArrayType2 = array of TMyType2;
```

What we now need to do is to "convert" arrays of type `TMyArrayType2` into `TMyArrayType1`. Why? Maybe for backward or forward compatibility reasons, maybe to reduce data sizes where possible, but handling just one type in most methods of our application (here: `TMyType1`) to avoid overloading many and many methods to handle both types, etc. Let's say, both array types have their benefits, so replacing one by another is not an option.

As all the possible values of `TMyType2` are fitting into `TMyType1`, we could do something like:

```
procedure Convert(const[ref] ASource: TMyArrayType2; var ADest: TMyArrayType1);
var
   ALen, i: Integer;
begin
     ALen:= Length(ASource);
     SetLength(ADest, ALen);
     FOR i:=0 TO ALen-1 DO
      begin
           ADest[i]:= ASource[i];
      end;
end;
```

Which compiles, but as we can imagine, this can be terribly slow with big arrays and also can be a performance issue when often used (maybe in loops, etc.), even with smaller arrays.

So is there a way to speed that up?

In best case we could "move" the data "in a bunch" (like with `System.Move` method), instead of setting one by one.
But as `TMyType1` and `TMyType2` have different sizes, I cannot imagine of a method that can handle this. This would mean copying a "pattern" of data (as reading 2 Bytes and using only the first one) like copying a "masked" area in an image, instead of copying pixel by pixel, wouldn't that be great?).

After thinking a lot and throwing away some ideas with "moving" (with `System.Move`) data first into an array of packed records which are each holding the lower and upper Bytes of `TMyArrayType1` (and than?), I got stuck, and so I think that there is no real solution to that problem and now I am wondering if somebody of you can tell me that I am wrong.

Comment: `this can be terribly slow` -Are you sure this is the main bottleneck of program? Usage of  SSE instructions might accelerate conversion in 2-5 times, but real work/calculations with these arrays usually takes 10x times comparing with conversion

Comment: @MBo It **can** be a performace issue some times. For example I experienced that copying Bytes out ouf `TBytes` one after another into an `array of byte` took some seconds when using `System.Move` was done in milliseconds using the same data. After that, using the resulting array was a lot faster than filling it, of course that depends on what you are doing with that data. Even small performance loss can be multiplied to a big one later, so i find it allways a good idea to find the best performance alternative when creating new data structures that are designed to be heavily used

Comment: I've just made test for your example with 400 000 000 size arrays.  266 ms for := and  109 ms for move... About conversion - as I said, you can write code with SSE assembler at the price of portability (small change for 32/64 bits, but unapplicable for some platforms). The game is worth the candle if conversion is used intensively. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126198/how-to-optimize-this-delphi-function-with-sse2/10135750#10135750)

Comment: This doesn't smell right. Seconds vs milliseconds seems wrong. Most likely your are trying to solve a problem that you have mis diagnosed

Comment: I also question why you use subrange types rather than built in types with the same range. Surely it's always preferable to use built in standard types.

Comment: @MBo I changed my test to meet your 400 000 000 size. 606ms to 912ms for := and 42ms for move. With {R+} I get 1084ms-1132ms for := and 42ms-46ms for move. On user pc I got with {R-}: 2387ms-2425ms for := and 342ms-409ms for move. I think the difference is big enough to think about it. But you are right, the price of portability would be too high when only setting on assembler. That could be solved with compiler defines, so asm where possible, slower alternative where not possible.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `Seconds vs milliseconds seems wrong` yes you are right, that was too vague and sounds like more than was meant. I should have been more concrete: ca. 3s vs ca. 500ms were measured some time ago on my previous dev machine. Test case was using data of a specific file, so test results are not compareable to those discussed with MBo, but I remember my feeling, that it lasts too long with := and so I optimized it with move. That has made a big difference for me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `why you use subrange types` I thought it would better demonstrate the size difference of the two types in that example. You are right, in most cases it is preferable to use built in standard types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small test with primitive time measuring. Assembler routine treats 4 elements per turn.

```
procedure WordsToDwords(pw, pd: Pointer; const Size: Integer);
//x86 32 bit, register calling convention - three parameters in EAX, EDX, ECX
asm
  pxor XMM2, XMM2
  shr ecx, 2  //size should be divisible by 4
  @@cycle:
    movq XMM1, [eax]
    punpcklwd XMM1, XMM2 //words to dwords
    movdqu [edx], XMM1
    add eax, 8        // inc pointers
    add edx, 16
    loop @@cycle
end;

var
  w: TArray<Word>;
  d: TArray<DWord>;
  n, i:  Integer;
  t1, t2, t3: DWord;    

begin
  n := 250000000;
  SetLength(w, n);
  SetLength(d, n);
  for i := 0 to n-1 do
    w[i] := i and $FFFF;
  t1 := GetTickCount();
  for i := 0 to n-1 do
     d[i] := w[i];
  t2 := GetTickCount();
  WordsToDwords(@w[0], @d[0], n);
  t3 := GetTickCount();
  Memo1.Lines.Add((t2-t1).ToString +' ' + (t3-t2).ToString);
  for i := 255 to 257 do  //to check
    memo1.Lines.Add(d[i].ToString);
end;
```

This code unpacks 500 megabytes of words into 1 GB of dwords.

At machine with memory throughput 12 GB/sec (Haswell Xeon 3.1 GHz, single-channel DDR3-1600 memory): debug mode exe gives 516/219 ms for assigning method and asm unpacking, release mode exe gives ~220 ms for both methods  - note treatment of 7 GB/sec, so memory limits the speed (reading-writing small blocks from distinct addresses)

At machine with memory throughput 45 GB/sec (Ryzen 5600G, dual-channel DDR4-3200): debug mode exe gives 227/119 ms for assigning method and asm unpacking, release mode exe gives 108/78 ms for both methods, code treats 14/18 GB/sec, so memory limits the speed again.

Seems **7-14 gigabytes per second** cannot be a real bottleneck

Comment: I think you made your point. Your answer convinces me. I got 672/94 with your code. Any idea why my measurements always have a greater difference from := to move/asm than yours have? Yours are most near factor 2 from move/asm to :=, mines are factor 5 to 15. And we both tested on different machines. Strange, isn't it?

Comment: Don't know. I think compiler code generation did not change a lot (xe7 vs 11). Perhaps different cpu power / memory relation